# How to separate static and dynamic content in servlet filter

Tags: tomcat, servlets, servlet-filters

I need to implement javax.servlet.ServletFilter which adds some pre-processing for all dynamic content in the Tomcat servlet container. But all static content such as images and HTML files should escape preprocessing.

The question is how to determine where the URI is static (will be handled by DefaultServlet) or dynamic one?

As I understand I can check this by inspecting URI. For example, if uri.endWith(".png") and this is "static" PNG image, but this is not ideal solution. I may forget to specify some "exotic" extention, etc.

Is there any general solution? May be Tomcat specific?

Comment: Why dont you go the opposite way? Specify the dynamic extensions and all the rest as static... ?

Comment: The set of "dynamic" extensions is not defined as well :) These are definitely JSPs. But  servlets and some JSPs have quite exotic name mappings. So the tasks of finding "static" and "dynamic" content are equivalent.